# How to configure what happens when I click on a tel: hyperlink in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

How do I set up Chrome on Ubuntu so that when I click on a tel: link it opens up my Zoom Phone please?

Thanks,

Ed.

Comment: It is true that on my system (where I have installed GSConnect also as a `tel:` handler and Zoom is installed as a **snap**), only Firefox (which is also installed as a **snap** on my system) displays both apps as handlers, but Chrome and Edge (these are **not snaps**) only display GSConnect and not Zoom as a `tel:` handler. So, the problem may be related to Zoom being a snap. Please, check your system and update your question accordingly.